# Align the left of Kendo UI bar charts

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

[image]

I have a bar chart as above. I am creating three charts from a json file.

I need to align the left of all the charts so that its all in the same line

```
 function ShowResults() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/Ajax/xyz.aspx?requesttype=xxxx&y=2",
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (JSON.parse(data).length > 0) {
                                var chartData = JSON.parse(data);
                                CreateEatingChart(chartData);
                                CreateExerciseChart(chartData);
                                CreateCopingChart(chartData);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                function CreateEatingChart(_chartData) {
                    var result = $.grep(_chartData, function (e) { return e.Pattern_Type == 'Eating'; });
                    var lowResult = $.grep(result, function (e) { return e.Score <= 50; });
                    var highResult = $.grep(result, function (e) { return e.Score > 50; });


                    $("#divEating").kendoChart({
                        seriesColors: ["green", "red"],

                        chartArea: {
                            background: ""
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: "Eating",
                            font: "18px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif bold",
                            color: 'black'
                        },

                        legend: {
                            visible: false,
                        },

                        chartArea: {
                            background: ""
                        },

                        seriesDefaults: {
                            type: "bar",
                            stack: true,
                            overlay: {
                                gradient: "none"
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'lowResult',
                            data: lowResult,
                            field: "Score",
                            categoryField: "PatternName"
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'highResult',
                            data: highResult,
                            field: "Score",
                            categoryField: "PatternName"
                        }],

                        valueAxis: {
                            majorGridLines: {
                                visible: true
                            },

                            labels: {
                                visible: false,                                    
                            }
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            visible: true

                        }
                    });

                }
```

Is it possible to pad the labels on the the left side with an empty string so that they all have the same width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to do it from css, since it is created from svg.
The only trick that I can find out is to add `&nbsp;` thus each chart has the same category length.

http://jsfiddle.net/bochzchan/H4wy9/

```
categoryAxis: { 
            categories: ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
            majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
             }
},
```